# Unexpected error while passing variable group variables (Azure DevOps) to YAML pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, terraform, azure-pipelines, terraform-provider-azure, azure-pipelines-yaml

I'm a newbie to both Azure DevOps and Terraform but, I'm trying to deploy a pipeline using a YAML file.

I have tried to run a `terraform plan` using a YAML file and passing variables (from AZ DevOps) but, I got the following error:

```
 
2021-11-24T18:39:46.4604561Z Error: "name" may only contain alphanumeric characters, dash, underscores, parentheses and periods
2021-11-24T18:39:46.4604832Z 
2021-11-24T18:39:46.4605940Z   on modules/aks/main.tf line 2, in resource "azurerm_resource_group" "aks-resource-group":
2021-11-24T18:39:46.4606436Z    2:   name     = var.resource_group_name
2021-11-24T18:39:46.4606609Z 
2021-11-24T18:39:46.4606722Z 
2021-11-24T18:39:46.4606818Z 
2021-11-24T18:39:46.4607525Z Error: Error: Subnet: (Name "#{vnet_subnet_name}#" / Virtual Network Name "#{vnet_name}#" / Resource Group "RG-XX-XXXX-XXXXX-001") was not found
2021-11-24T18:39:46.4608006Z 
2021-11-24T18:39:46.4608580Z   on modules/aks/main.tf line 16, in data "azurerm_subnet" "subnet-project":
2021-11-24T18:39:46.4609335Z   16: data "azurerm_subnet" "subnet-project" {
```

The 'name' has the following format at the Variable group in the Azure DevOps UI:

```
RG-XX-XXXX-XXXXX-001
```

This is the snippet of where I included the replace token at the YAML file:

```
          displayName: 'Replace Secrets'
          inputs:
            targetFiles: |
              variables.tfvars
              encoding: 'utf-8'
            actionOnMissing: fail
            tokenPattern: #{MyVar}#
```

And this is a sample of the variables I have in a variable group:
[variable-group-sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D7jqv.png)

Also, I replace the `terraform.tfvars` file with something like this:

```
resource_group_name   = "#{resource_group_name}#"
```

I have checked the name inserted at the UI several times but I feel the error is pointing to something else I cannot see.

Have anyone experienced something related to this error?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

```
tokenPattern: #{MyVar}#
```

It is looking for the pattern `#{MyVar}#` to replace. Not "something contained between `#{` and `}#`, but the actual value `#{MyVar}#`. I'm guessing it's expecting a regular expression, but I'm not familiar with that task.

So the end result is that your `#{token values}#` aren't getting replaced.

Assuming you're using https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.replacetokens, you probably want to specify `tokenPrefix: #{` and `tokenSuffix: }#` instead of using `tokenPattern`.

Now, having said that...

There is **no reason** for you to be using token replacement on a `tfvars` file. You should create different `tfvars` files for each environment, then pass in a `tfvars` file via the `-var-file` argument to Terraform. Secrets can be passed in on the command line via `-var 'foo=bar'`

Storing variables that represent application or deployment configuration in Azure DevOps (or GitHub, or any other CI system) is a big, big anti-pattern, because it's tightly coupling your deployment process to a particular platform. If you're sourcing all of your variables from Azure DevOps, you can't easily test locally or migrate to a different CI/CD provider like GitHub Actions in the future.

For values that shouldn't be in source control, such a secrets, you should use a secret provider like Azure KeyVault and integrate it with your application (or, in this case, use a `data` resource in Terraform to pull the necessary secrets automatically at deployment time).

Comment: Hi Daniel, thank you for your input. I will check again what's the best approach to this project infrastructure. I will have a look to all your suggestion to work with best practices.

As for the question I made, your answer solved it. Also, the part `tokenPattern: #{MyVar}#` also works fine. My mistake was with another variable I was calling wrong.

Thank you again!